# logging Hibernate queries - set in BOTH log4j.properties and persistence.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, persistence

While struggling to see Hibernate-generated SQL queries in JBoss7 log, I'm looking for a definitive answer to following question:

Q: Should entries in both of these config locations be present AT THE SAME TIME, or does any one override another?

1) in log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=ALL #or DEBUG
```

2) in persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit...>
   <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      ...
```

This is a vital question for me as I can only edit 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement for logging are these (ofc you have to specify a file appender):

1) on **log4j2.xml**

```
//if you put this to trace, you'll log the variables putted into the queries
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level='trace' additivity="false" >
    <appender-ref ref='FileLog'></appender-ref>
</logger>
```

2) on **log4j2.xml**

```
//with debug, you will log the query itself
<logger name='org.hibernate.SQL' level='debug' additivity='false'>
  <appender-ref ref='FileLog'></appender-ref>
</logger>
```

3) on **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

**EDIT:** this is an example of appender

```
<appenders>
   <File name="FileLog" fileName="c:/path/your.log"></File>
</appenders>
```

Comment: OK, so I understand from this that they work in conjunction (not override one another). That is: I have to set BOTH (which I am unable to do, but good to know this is how it works).